Generating arbitrary state/bit using Blum Blum Shub generaor. Simplification of Carmichael function term?
From wikipedia:

An interesting characteristic of the Blum Blum Shub generator is the possibility to calculate any $x_i$ value directly (via Euler's theorem):
$$x_i = \left( x_0^{2^i \bmod \lambda(M)} \right) \bmod M$$
where $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function. (Here we have $\lambda(M) = \lambda(p\cdot q) = \operatorname{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$).

However, in several sources (example, see top of page 3) I saw it mentioned as:
$$x_i = \left( x_0^{2^i \bmod (p - 1)(q - 1)   } \right) \bmod M$$
... i.e. somehow $\color{red}{\lambda(M)} = \lambda(p\cdot q) = \operatorname{lcm}(p-1, q-1) = \color{red}{(p - 1)(q - 1)}$
How can we arrive at that?

If $p$ and $q$ are odd distinct primes, then $\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)=(p-1)(q-1)$ never stands. Hint about why the question's conclusion is incorrect: from $\forall x,\ x^u\bmod M=x^v\bmod M$, it can't be concluded that $u=v$. Counterexample $M=65$, $u=7$, $v=19$. The definition of the Carmichael $\lambda$ function will help.
